# Removing all material slots in one go

Tags: python

I need some help in removing all material slots in one go using a python script.
I am able to use this, would prefer to ave all removed.

```
bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 0
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 1
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 2
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
```

Comment: You'll find some good answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27190/35559)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also remove all material slots without calling the operator at all, so you don't have to bother with indexes:

```
bpy.context.object.data.materials.clear()
```

In general, I would always try to avoid calling operators unless they do something very specific that is difficult to achieve via calling usual API functions.

Comment: That would remove the materials, not the slots.

Comment: Sort of. All materials get removed from the data-block by removing all material slots as well. Afterwards the materials do still exist, but they are no longer linked to the object. Unfortunately the [Blender API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.IDMaterials.html#bpy.types.IDMaterials.clear) is not very specific here.

Comment: Wonder if calling `object.data.materials.clear()` then calling `object.material_slot_remove_unused()` is a safe idea - if it works, could be a better solution I guess

Answer (score 11):

You can set the index of the list to `0`, iterate through all slots and override the context of [`material_slot_remove()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=material_slot_remove#bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove).

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for obj in context.selected_editable_objects:
    obj.active_material_index = 0
    for i in range(len(obj.material_slots)):
        with context.temp_override(object=obj):
            bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_editable_objects:
    obj.active_material_index = 0
    for i in range(len(obj.material_slots)):
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove({'object': obj})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the part of overwriting the context?

Comment: Further reading: [poll() failed, context incorrect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6105/31447) @MikeW

Answer (score 6):

```
import bpy #import the blender python library
for x in bpy.context.object.material_slots: #For all of the materials in the selected object:
    bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 0 #select the top material
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove() #delete it
```